# Self-host a REST web-service for Geonames

Tags: web-services, rest, geocoding, self-hosting

I'm using Geonames.org for textbox [auto-complete](http://www.geonames.org/export/ajax-postalcode-autocomplete.html). Very neat feature.

They provide both the database and a REST endpoint, something like this: http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username=demo

However, as per the requirement (decrease auto-complete latency, eliminate external resource dependency) I wish to host the database on my server. Geonames provides the database for export, which is nice. However, then I'm facing a task of writing my own REST service solution for accessing my database with imported geo data.

At the same time, I don't think I'm the only person facing an issue like this, so I was wondering what your takes on this are? What's the fastest, the best solution would be in this situation? Is it really necessary to write a REST service from scratch? Or is there a library for that, and I just can't find it?

Environment: ASP.NET (but it's probably going to be a separate web-application anyways, so I'm open to other offerings such as Node.js, Ruby on Rails - whatever will be the least development time).

Comment: So we ended up writing our own library.

Comment: Any ideas to whether to open-source your library?

Comment: We ended up ending up not using Geonames at all :) And no, I don't think open sourcing is a possibility right now. An alternative would be MongoDB - from what I've seen it's really easy to write GEO queries: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/

Comment: Any info on what was the alternative dataset you used (instead of Geonames)? Is it public data set or some other commercial solution?